# Is there find_or_create_by_ that takes a hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's some of my production code (I had to force line breaks):

```
task = Task.find_or_create_by_username_and_timestamp_and_des \
cription_and_driver_spec_and_driver_spec_origin(username,tim \
estamp,description,driver_spec,driver_spec_origin)
```

Yes, I'm trying to find or create a unique `ActiveRecord::Base` object.  But in current form it's very ugly.  Instead, I'd like to use something like this:

```
task = Task.SOME_METHOD :username => username, :timestamp => timestamp ...
```

I know about `find_by_something key=>value`, but it's not an option here.  I need all values to be unique.  Is there a method that'll do the same as `find_or_create_by`, but take a hash as an input?  Or something else with similat semantics?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rails 3.2 first introduced [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) to ActiveRecord.  Not only does it have the requested functionality, but it also fits in the rest of the ActiveRecord relations:

```
Task.where(attributes).first_or_create
```

In Rails 3.0 and 3.1:

```
Task.where(attributes).first || Task.create(attributes)
```

In Rails 2.1 - 2.3:

```
Task.first(:conditions => attributes) || Task.create(attributes)
```

In the older versions, you could always write a method called `find_or_create` to encapsulate this if you'd like. Definitely done it myself in the past:

```
class Task
  def self.find_or_create(attributes)
    # add one of the implementations above
  end
end
```

Comment: Yea, you can certainly add it to AR::Base, but I find there is some model-specific behavior, like you may want to chose specific unique columns to do the find. But you can always override it, too.

Answer (score 3):

I also extend the @wuputah's method to take in an array of hashes, which is very useful when used inside `db/seeds.rb`

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_or_create(attributes)
    if attributes.is_a?(Array)
      attributes.each do |attr|
        self.find_or_create(attr)
      end
    else
      self.first(:conditions => attributes) || self.create(attributes)
    end
  end
end


# Example
Country.find_or_create({:name => 'Aland Islands', :iso_code => 'AX'})

# take array of hashes
Country.find_or_create([
  {:name => 'Aland Islands', :iso_code => 'AX'},
  {:name => 'Albania', :iso_code => 'AL'},
  {:name => 'Algeria', :iso_code => 'DZ'}
])
```